# Можно ли объединить в одну form, input раскиданные по странице?

Tags: html, html5

То есть как правильно это сделать? У меня есть много input на странице и 3 button.
Как их объединить в 1 form?

Comment: если внутри страницы нет других форм, то можно в форму засунуть хоть всё, что внутри `body`. и тогда все "раскиданные" элементы будут сабмититься вместе

Comment: а если сделать много форм и дать им одно и тоже имя, так будет работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тега `input` можно задать атрибут `form` с указанием идентификатора нужной формы.

```
<input type="<тип>" form="<идентификатор>">
<form id="<идентификатор>">...</form>
```

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/form)